# How to run hello world in Maemo

Tags: maemo

Do you know any other way to start app than using `./`? I've just compiled one in c++ and i can't run it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the application in your user's home directory, then you'll need to call it via a path to it (ie, either ./program or /home/user/program).  Or, you can put it into a component of your path like /usr/bin or something (but that'll eat up precious space on your maemo device).  Or, put it in a new path location like ~user/bin and add that path to your default PATH by putting this in your ~user/profile:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Or, you could create a desktop file (which goes into /usr/share/applications/hildon/) which will allow you to execute the program from the normal list of programs in the application list.